# Cannot seem to create a new Web application with Visual Studio 2015 with Update 2

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I haven't created a "**new**" web application in weeks, as **I have been opening existing applications.** (With no problems)

I did install **Update 2** for **Visual Studio 2015** Enterprise a week ago. 
( I did the same on work computer and it creates new web application projects/solutions with no issue).

Web Application - Web Api or MVC ,   tried different directories.  Tried different versions of the .net framework   4.5.1 to 4.6.x

[image]

bottom bar of IDE says   "Creating project 'WebApplication6'... project creation failed.

So much fun.....

Removing Enterprise 15 Preview  - I wonderful if that caused the problem. Forgot about that careless installation  yikes.

Update    :    I saw some issue with application insights....    I was trying to install just that.   I noticed that I can install a console app...   So it is just web.    Going for a repair now.

Comment: Debating.   Reboot computer,  clear temp files...   ,  remove update 2, ...  most things with probably take hours of my life away ...  booo

Comment: @downvoter ,  take a hike,  you don't belong on SO

Comment: Rebooted,  no luck on the simple

Comment: use ProcessMonitor to see which folders/fies are not found

Comment: ok, ya I see a bit more  thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,  I ran a **repair**  via add/remove programs.   Fixed now.

Comment: I wish that I found the real culprit to not have to take that long repair,  but when an open solution which was empty would not let me then even add new project ,  I got a message about it not finding application insights  v. 14 ,  i searched a while,  but gave up